# Using SSRS Expressions to see which options a user has selected from a multivalued parameter?

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

I'm trying to set up a filter against a "Totals" column in an SSRS report using an expression for the field.

I have a multivalued parameter setup with the values value1, value2, value3, and value4 as options.

Before the filter, this totals column just simply added the integer values from the different columns.  I want to add functionality to where you can check which of the values the user has selected.

Similar to below (Pseudo code, because I can't figure out the syntax):

`=IIF(Parameters!<Parameter>.Label="value1",Fields!value1.Value,0)
+IIF(Parameters!<Parameter>.Label="value2",Fields!value2.Value,0) 
+IIF(Parameters!<Parameter>.Label="value3",Fields!value3.Value,0) 
+IIF(Parameters!<Parameter>.Label="value4",Fields!value4.Value,0)`

All values in the fields being added are simple integers.  I'd appreciate any help anyone can provide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a parameter called `Include`, you can use an expression like this:

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!Include.Value, ","), "value1") > 0, Fields!value1.Value, 0)
    + IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!Include.Value, ","), "value2") > 0, Fields!value2.Value, 0)
    + IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!Include.Value, ","), "value3") > 0, Fields!value3.Value, 0)
    + IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!Include.Value, ","), "value4") > 0, Fields!value4.Value, 0)
```

This uses the `Join` function to create a comma-delimited string of the selected parameters, checks for a particular parameter value being selected, then add either the corresponding value or 0 to the total.

Here's a simple report with the expression:

[image]

All values selected:

[image]

Two values selected:

[image]

Comment: This approach is good enough for simple cases but it has the problem that if there are ten fields called `value1` to `value10` then every time `value10` is selected, `value1` will also be included in the total (as well as being boring to type and maintain those field names if used across several reports).

Comment: @ChrisLätta, you can deal with the case above by updating the `IIf` expression slightly: `IIf(InStr("," & Join(Parameters!Include.Value, ",") & ",", ",value10,")`. I thought about custom code for this, but for four columns it's probably a step too far. Agree for more columns it would probably tip over to custom code. With custom code it's helpful to have tight coupling between parameter values and field names; hardly inconvenient but just another consideration. All  depends on the circumstances at the time.

Comment: Agreed - for simple cases in one report with a few fields and non-overlapping field names your method is certainly quick and easy, +1

Answer (score 3):

You can acheive this in a simple way without stringing together a whole bunch of `IIF` functions and specifying each and every field to be used. What if you want to change the name of a field or add fields?

Using custom code we can have a simple and robust way of performing this calculation. Right-click on the non-design surface of your report, click `Report Properties...` and then click on the `Code` tab. Insert the following code:

```
Function CalcTotal (ByVal param As Parameter, flds AS Fields) AS Integer
  Dim Result As Integer
  Result = 0
  If param.IsMultiValue then
    For i as integer = 0 to param.Count-1 
        Result = Result + flds(param.Value(i)).Value 
    Next 
  End If 

  Return Result
End Function
```

This takes the parameter *object* (not value) and iterates through the values selected to perform the calculation using the fields in the `Fields` collection.

Now for your expression, just use:

```
=Code.CalcTotal(Parameters!Include, Fields)
```

Comment: A great option.  I decided to go with a quick expression-defined field instead, however.