# How to Check If a Parameter Contains a Certain Value in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools, reportingservices-2005

SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) - How to Check If a Parameter Contains a Certain Value in SSRS ?

Example:

I have a paramter named SubjectID which has few subjectID's say 603,604,605,607,608 .
I want to return "Y" if the subject ID is 603,604 and 605 else return "N"

Is there any function to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052101/using-ssrs-expressions-to-see-which-options-a-user-has-selected-from-a-multivalu

Comment: =IIF(InStr("603,604,605", Parameters!SubjectID.Value) ,"Y","N") . Guess this too works using InStr function.

Comment: If  we use IIF(InStr("603,604,605", Parameters!SubjectID.Value)>0 ,"Y","N")  then it returns true or false , without the checking of zero it returns 0 and 1.

Comment: =IIF(Array.indexOf(Split("603,604,605,607,608", ","),  Parameters!SubjectID.Value) > 0, "Y", "N")